# R ggplot how to expand the interval on the horizontal axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset with 100 Timestamp points. While when I plot the chart, the horizontal axis indicates all time points, and so all time points were overlapped together. How to indicates some regular time points on the horizontal axis rather than show all of them?

```html
 EU
              T_DCEP    DCEP
1    05/02/2016 1:28 1.14596
2    05/02/2016 1:39 1.14684
3    05/02/2016 2:04 1.14488
4    05/02/2016 3:15 1.14820
5    05/02/2016 3:34 1.14750
6    05/02/2016 4:40 1.14915
7    05/02/2016 4:56 1.14849
8    05/02/2016 5:22 1.14913
9    05/02/2016 5:55 1.14761
10   05/02/2016 6:07 1.14821
.   ...              ..
```

My code:

```
ggplot(EU,aes(T_DCEP,DCEP, group = 1)) + geom_line()+geom_point()
```

[image]

Comment: you may want to show some sample data so that other can help. for example, you could show sth like the output of `dput(head(EU))`.

Comment: You may have a `factor` issue. Check `class(EU$T_DCEP)`. If it is a factor or character class, it will print as you illustrate. Convert to a date class and it will print more neatly.

Comment: You right, I need to convert the class of the EU$T_DCEP, Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `class` of the variables matter when plotting. Convert to a valid date-time class to solve the problem:

```
#Example data
set.seed(451)
dates <- seq(Sys.time()-99, Sys.time(), length.out=100)
df <- data.frame(x=dates, y=rnorm(100))
head(df)
#                     x          y
# 1 2016-11-04 09:49:09 -0.9431540
# 2 2016-11-04 09:49:10  0.7257408
# 3 2016-11-04 09:49:11  2.5257787
# 4 2016-11-04 09:49:12  1.1916054
# 5 2016-11-04 09:49:13  3.1091791
# 6 2016-11-04 09:49:14  0.2848636

class(df$x)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"
```

This example will plot correctly because it is a proper date-time class.

```
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]

But if I did not have a proper date-time class, it would look like your example.

```
df$x <- as.character(dates)
ggplot(df, aes(x, y, group=1)) + geom_point() + geom_line()
```

[image]